# How to display activity indicator in center of tableview footer center?

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an indicator view. How i can display it in tableview footer center.

[image: my indicator]

Comment: Apply `Horizontal` & `Vertical` center constraint to indicator in `UITableView` footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can center it programmatically like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  if section == 0 {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
    footerView.addSubview(activityView)
    activityView.startAnimating()

    activityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: activityView, 
      attribute: .CenterX, 
      relatedBy: .Equal, 
      toItem: footerView, 
      attribute: .CenterX, 
      multiplier: 1.0, 
      constant: 0.0
    ).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(
      item: activityView, 
      attribute: .CenterY, 
      relatedBy: .Equal, 
      toItem: footerView, 
      attribute: .CenterY, 
      multiplier: 1.0, 
      constant: 0.0
    ).active = true

    return footerView
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```